# Cant call method with array argument c#

Tags: c#, arrays, polymorphism

Im following a tutorial based on SOLID principles but i fail to understand how to actually implement this method, here is the tutorial [Link](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-simple-example-of-the-openclosed-principle/)

I faily understand the concept of the code but i cant figure out how to actually call the AreaCalculator.Area method from my Main

How do i call the method to either calculate the Rectangle Area or the Circle Area? based on the code in the tutorial

```
Area(Circle with 10 radius);
Area(Rectangle with 10 width and 5 height);
```

Shape.cs

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double Area();
}
```

Circle.cs

```
    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public double Radius { get; set; }
        public override double Area()
        {
            return Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
        }
    }
```

Rectangle.cs

```
    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public override double Area()
        {
            return Width * Height;
        }
    }
```

AreaCalculator.cs

```
public static double Area(Shape[] shapes)
        {
            double area = 0;
            foreach (var shape in shapes)
            {
                area += shape.Area();
            }

            return area;
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Side note: *interface* (say, `IShapable`) instead of *abstract class* (`Shape`) will be more resilient. `public static double Area(IEnumerable<IShapable> shapes)` - note *interface* `IEnumerable` - is also more flexible

Comment: Talking about flexible, it could also be `double Area(params Shape[] shapes)`

Comment: @Cleptus I would prefer `IEnumerable` because `Area` is unlikely to be called with a single item, and `IEnumerable` would allow an existing collection to be used rather than potentially forcing a new array to be allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var circle = new Circle { Radius = 10 };                  // Create a circle
var rectangle = new Rectangle { Width = 10, Height = 5 }; // Create a rectangle

var shapes = new Shape[] { circle, rectangle };           // Create array of shapes

double area = AreaCalculator.Area(shapes);                // Call Area method with array
```

---

If you only need the area of a single shape, the `AreaCalculator` is unneccesary; simply call the `Area` method on an individual shape:

```
double circleArea = circle.Area();
double rectangleArea = rectangle.Area();
```

Comment: *How do i call the method to either calculate the Rectangle Area or the Circle Area?* Are you sure author needs the sum of this areas?

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I've updated the answer; with a single shape using the `AreaCalculator` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! It made me understand this example better!

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Even `AreaCalculator` is unnecessary and can be easily replaced by short LINQ statement.

Comment: @ScreamoIsDead Did you come closer to understanding not how this example works, but to understanding open/closed principle?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate instances of each shape and pass those as an array to the `AreaCalculator.Area()` method. The key take away is the `Area` method will take any objects that extend `Shape`.

```cs
var circle = new Circle();
circle.Radius = 5;

var rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.Width = 10;
rectangle.Height = 3;

var area = AreaCalculator.Area(new Shape[] {circle, rectangle});
```

Or more succinctly

```cs
AreaCalculator.Area(new Shape[]{
    new Circle() {Radius = 5},
    new Rectangle() {Width = 10, Height = 3}
});
```

Comment: Your second example won't compile, because the array cannot be implicitly typed.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay good call, edited to make it compile. That what happens when you write code in an html textbox

Comment: Thank you! it helped me understand this a bit better:)